# In ExtJS, how do I make store.load(config) send parameters not limited to the predefined?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm performing a remote filter to a store.

I code something like this:

```
myStore.load({
    limit: 8,
    foo: 'foo is never sent',
    filters:[{'property':'some property','value':30,'comparison':'lt','field':'age'}]
});
```

It ends up sending to the server using GET method, with parameters below: (from chrome/firebug)

```
_dc:1327757119914
page:1
start:0
limit:8
filter:[{"property":"some property","value":30}]
```

requested URL:

```
myServerPage.php?_dc=1327757119914&page=1&start=0&limit=8&filter=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22some%20property%22%2C%22value%22%3A30%7D%5D
```

the 'foo' is missing, and more importantly, in the passing 'filter' object, only 'property' and 'value' was sent. (I think these two are predefined, filter config does not accept other keys and values)

How can I send my own parameters to the server using load(), especially in the 'filters' part?

Comment: I think you need to improve your question with *real* examples, because not only is *foo* never sent, but neither is *filters* -- instead you say it sends *something like this* (not very precise) and then it contains *filter* not *filters*

Comment: thanks for your advice. I made some editing to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myStore.load({
  params: {
    foo: 'foo'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

another way:

```
myStore.getProxy().extraParams= {search: "something"}
```

Comment: This method allow set parameters on fly. This solution is better

Comment: Thanks for the vote up. Actually this solution is better when you want to preserve the parameters across multiple requests. The load with params method is better for on the fly data.

Comment: Yes, but when I use Ext.Net I can't always call load method, but I need to change parameters before load and between loads. In this case your way is better.